# Why Is Object Still In Memory Snapshot After Destructor Called

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, prism

I'm investigating a memory leak and am wondering why after the destructor is called the object Count and Size doesn't change in the memory snapshot. It does look like the Inclusive Size does go down, but not to zero. There are two rows as the first is a view and the second is its view model.

[image: Memory Snapshot Compared To Before Destructor Breakpoint Hit]

Can anyone explain why this happens? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I just took another memory snapshot after writing this question up (maybe ~5 minutes later) and it seems the objects are now gone so maybe it just takes some time for everything to go away like longer than a few seconds after the destructor?

Comment: what type of object is it? theres different levels of gc. i suggest you read up on that

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you be a little more specific with regard to what you mean by "type?" Do you mean which generation or some priority property?

Comment: what size of object is it? does it have unmanaged references, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why . . . the destructor is called the object Count and Size doesn't change in the memory snapshot

.NET doesn't have destructors.  It has [finalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors) which are only indirectly related to memory management.  An object with a finalizer cannot be garbage collected until after the finalizer is run (or you call [GC.SupressFinalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=netcore-3.1)).  But the object is not immediately garbage collected after its finalizer runs.

When GC finds an (otherwise) unreachable object with a finalizer a reference to the object is put on the freachable queue, and the finalizer thread runs the finalizer on all the objects that end up there.  The object will be eligible for garbage collection on the next GC run after its finalizer runs.  Note that since the object has already survived a GC it will be at least on Gen1.  And if it's on Gen2 it may be a while until it's collected.

The decision to reuse C++ destructor syntax for C# finalizers was probably a mistake.